# Send data from running socket server to a client socket connected through terminal

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I have a server socket running on terminal through below command

```
php5 server_socket.php
```

I also have a client connected to this socket through terminal using

```
telnet 192.168.1.111 10000
```

Currently,Interactions are happening properly between Client & Server through terminal

Now I want to send data to client but not through the terminal,it will be from external php script who also should use the same resource i.e (192.168.1.111+10000)socket.